# Dynamical drawImage with for loops

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to dynamically create a canvas with 2 loops from an image, and to make the design effect "line by line" I set a timeout.

The problem is that for a moment,  the browser freezes and after a while comes out the full image without making the idea of ​​dynamic construction. This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var canv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var img=new Image();
img.src='img/myImage.jpg';
img.onload= function(){
for(var i=0;i<img.width;i++){
for(var j=0;j<img.height;j++){
setTimeout(function(){ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,i,j,0,0,i,j)},10);
   }
 }
}
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: wrap the setTimeout call in self invoking function:
(function(i, j){ /*setTimeout call */ })(i, j);

Comment: you would also probably wanna increment timeout duration to be able to really see the drawing happening

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `i` and `j` are used as closure variables and thus will have their last values when the timeout function is executed.

To workaround this, introduce a nice scope using an *IIFE*:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var canv = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
var img=new Image();
img.src='img/myImage.jpg';
img.onload= function(){
for(var i=0;i<img.width;i++){
for(var j=0;j<img.height;j++){
   (function(){
      var _i = i; // capture the current value of i
      var _j = j;
      setTimeout(function(){ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,_i,_j,0,0,_i,_j)},10);
   })();  // that's the IFFE
   }
 }
}
});
```

Also you should probably try a non-constant value for the time out. All setTimeOuts are initialized at almost the same time, so they will execute immediately after each other. Try something like `(i + j) * 5`.

Here is a slightly modified [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/tKgFP/).

Comment: Great! It wok now! only 1 problem, it return this error:IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount. it doesn't compromise the animation, i aske only for information!

Comment: @user2649996: No idea with the information at hand - can you modify my added fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: sorry, it was a browser problem! your code work perfectly! tnx!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a line by line effect you don't have to use canvas as there is an easier solution to this:
Just use an `<img />` inside of a container that has `height: 0` and `overflow: hidden`.

Then increase the height of the container line by line. It's easy as this:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://api.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/logo-jquery.png" />
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#container").css("height", "+=1");
    }, 100);
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jkyvk/

Comment: it's a good solution too!sorry but i'm very noob in js! tnx very much!